# Install Ubuntu over Windows while keeping files

Tags: windows

I want to install  the latest Ubuntu version for the first time in my life.

My system is Windows 8, and I want to replace it without losings my files and documents.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. If you just want to try Ubuntu and you are using a relatively powerful machine, you can use a Virtual Machine like Virtual Box. It's free and there are plenty of guides out there that tell you how to use Ubuntu on a VM. Additionally, you may have heard of Wubi which would be relevant here but it does have issues with Windows 8. For more information, see Wubi: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide. This is risk-free approach.

If you are dead set on using Ubuntu and want it installed as a dual boot, you need to create a partition for it. You do this using a partitioner such as GParted. You will need at least 20G of space for Ubuntu. **Warning: Back up all of your data when resizing partitions. Resizing disks comes at a small risk of data loss + any derps!** Once you have resized your disk, you can simply install Ubuntu on the space you have reserved for it. A tutorial for GParted can be found here: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html. You can avoid partitioning completely by using a spare/multiple HDDs.

Once you have some disk space, simply run the Ubuntu ISO and ensure you select the reserved partition during the Install process. The installer will take care of the rest. Note that the installer will replace MBR with GRUB Boot Manager but GRUB will happily boot to Windows. In order to switch between the two, simply restart and select Ubuntu/Windows at start up. This will be the case for both BIOS and UEFI systems.

Simple!